# Keyboard Not showing FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL

Tags: java, android

I'm creating a floating messaging function like the Messenger app.

I fixed keyboard not showing on a service by using `FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL` on my Layout params, but when the service starts, other apps like google,
search apps on phone, the keyboard is not working.

Here's the first picture - showing that the keyboard is showing: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pc0Vs.png.

Second picture - my service starts: https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1kWZ.jpg

Third picture - keyboard not showing anymore: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P93Et.jpg

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                                                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                                                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
                                                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

the above code is my code for showing the keyboard on my service. Using the `FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL` shows the keyboard on my service, I tried replacing `FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL` with `FLAG_LOCAL_FOCUS_MODE` but still the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old question, but the first result for the issue

The issue is the overlay is still taking focus away from any editable views. Combine `FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL` with `FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE` to fix this

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL ||        

WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
```